# request.getSession().getId() versus session.getId()

Tags: java

I am working on some code by a departed consultant.  I am trying to understand if there is a difference between the **session** variable passed to the method, and the one that is returned by **req.getSession()**

When I inspect them in the debugger, they appear to be the same.  Is there a reason not to just get the id directly from **session.getId()** variable, rather than **req.getSesssion.getId()**?

```
public void enqueueRequest(
        HttpSession session,
        HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {

            req.getSession().removeAttribute(TIME_STAMP);
            ResponseCache.INSTANCE.remove(req.getSession().getId());
        }
}
```

vs

```
session.getId();
session.removeAttribute(TIME_STAMP);
```

Comment: Did you try putting `==` in the code to see if they are indeed the same object?

Comment: Can you check the calling code, how is it obtaining the session object? May be its retrieved from the request only.

Comment: getId() returns a string, and printing out the id show them to have the same id:  INFO: req31d8991cb365c181440bc664e60a
INFO: ses31d8991cb365c181440bc664e60a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpServletRequest#getSession` returns the current session Object associated with `http request`. If your `Session` object and `Session` Object associated with http request is same then id will be same as because `Object` is same.

As per [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29)

> Returns the current session associated with this request, or if the
>   request does not have a session, creates one.

Answer (score 2):

It's poor design. You're not going to be able to access anyone else's session, and the session is already available via the request, so the session argument is redundant. If you have the opportunity, delete it.